# (Is there a O(1) approach.) Given an array of characters, give an algorithm for removing the duplicates

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, hash, linear-search

Is there a O(1) solution.

**Approach :**

```
public void removeDuplicates(char[] a, int n){
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < n;){
               if(a[i] == a[j])
                   a[j] = s [--n];
               else  j++;
           }
       }
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
```

But the time complexity is **O(n^2).**
Can it be **optimised further ?**

Comment: O(n) is going to be your lower bound. There's no way to remove duplicates without looking at each element once.

Comment: i was wondering what hashing would do.

Comment: Anyways, O(1) in not possible

Comment: Right. Hashing is a good approach, but you still have to hash all n elements to eliminate duplicates, so you can't get to O(1).